# Google Sheet: Concatenate smart chips into rows only if rows in Column A are duplicated

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to consolidate a list of smart chips from column B into a single cell ONLY IF the index (ie., Column A) is duplicated. The issue is that my formula is unable to combine smart chips. Is it possible to alter the formula so that it can combine smart chips or am I out of luck? Thanks!

[Example Google Sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LrNOPHL8ehLK_8Vfm9QqTOY6b_phEZVwZr2MeVLUxzY/edit#gid=1595596214)

```
=LET(A, A6:A, ux, UNIQUE(A),idx, FILTER(XMATCH(ux, A), COUNTIF(A, ux)>0), 
 MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A)), LAMBDA(s, IF(ISNA(XMATCH(s, idx)), "", TEXTJOIN(", ",, 
 FILTER(B6:B, A=INDEX(A,s)))))))
```